# how can i read Arabic Language from phpmyadmin into html page

Tags: php, sql, database, arabic

I have a problem on reading Arabic language, when I read arabic text it displayed as a question marks like that

```
���� ����
```

Although my php page encoding as `Utf8`.

And all the table in my database collation `Utf8_general_ci`.

What should I do ?!!

Comment: What does PHPMyAdmin have to do with this? Are you asking how to configure MySQL+PHPMyAdmin to handle arabic text? Or are you asking how to write PHP to interact with MySQL that handles arabic text?

Comment: Also make sure that connection string is also utf8 with `SET CHARACTER SET utf8`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you must set charset in first connect with mysql through this query:

SET CHARACTER SET utf8

for example in mysqli functions

$MySQL_Handle = mysqli_connect(HOSTNAME,DATABASE_USERNAME,DATABASE_PASSWORD,DATABASE_NAME) 
or die ( mysqli_error($MySQL_Handle) );

$sSQL= 'SET CHARACTER SET utf8';

mysqli_query($MySQL_Handle,$sSQL) 
or die ('Can\'t charset in DataBase');

this action need before insert and before select.